# Replace Mysql com substring

Tags: mysql

Tenho informações salvas num campo mysql com o seguinte formato:

```
STRING STRING STRING    XXX
```

Separando essas strings existe 4 espaços.
Gostaria de retirar tudo que está após esses 4 espaços, porém não consegui uma forma de fazer todo o update ignorando tudo após eles.

Algo como `update tabela set campo = campo-(tudo depois dos 4 espaços)`

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é usar o `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, você pode dizer que quer cortar a string a partir da primeira posição quando encontrar os 4 espaços, da seguinte maneira.

```
UPDATE
  tabela
SET campo = SUBSTRING_INDEX(campo, '    ', 1);
```

O 1 indica que você quer cortar até o primeiro `índice` da `string`, sendo assim tudo que tem antes de 4 espaços.